# DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. "..." is not visible at this point

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix, chainlink

I am practising this tutorial in Remix IDE - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aXumgdpnPU

I saw in the Chainlink documentation that their Randomness VRF code has been changed since the development of the video.

I started replacing the parts and trying to deploy the class via Remix but it gives an error which I am not sure how to fix.

Would you be able to check what I have as code and I'll send a screenshot of the error?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.11;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFV2WrapperConsumerBase.sol";

contract Lottery is
    VRFV2WrapperConsumerBase,
    ConfirmedOwner
    {
    address public owner;
    address payable[] public players;
    uint public lotteryId;
    mapping (uint => address payable) public lotteryHistory;


    event RequestSent(uint256 requestId, uint32 numWords);
    event RequestFulfilled(
        uint256 requestId,
        uint256[] randomWords,
        uint256 payment
    );

    struct RequestStatus {
        uint256 paid; // amount paid in link
        bool fulfilled; // whether the request has been successfully fulfilled
        uint256[] randomWords;
    }
    mapping(uint256 => RequestStatus)
        public s_requests; /* requestId --> requestStatus */

    // past requests Id.
    uint256[] public requestIds;
    uint256 public lastRequestId;

    // Depends on the number of requested values that you want sent to the
    // fulfillRandomWords() function. Test and adjust
    // this limit based on the network that you select, the size of the request,
    // and the processing of the callback request in the fulfillRandomWords()
    // function.
    uint32 callbackGasLimit = 100000;

    // The default is 3, but you can set this higher.
    uint16 requestConfirmations = 3;

    // For this example, retrieve 2 random values in one request.
    // Cannot exceed VRFV2Wrapper.getConfig().maxNumWords.
    uint32 numWords = 2;

    // Address LINK - hardcoded for Goerli
    address linkAddress = 0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB;

    // address WRAPPER - hardcoded for Goerli
    address wrapperAddress = 0x708701a1DfF4f478de54383E49a627eD4852C816;

    constructor()
    ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender)
        VRFV2WrapperConsumerBase(linkAddress, wrapperAddress)
    {
        owner = msg.sender;
        lotteryId = 1;
    }


    function requestRandomWords()
        external
        onlyOwner
        returns (uint256 requestId)
    {
        requestId = requestRandomness(
            callbackGasLimit,
            requestConfirmations,
            numWords
        );
        s_requests[requestId] = RequestStatus({
            paid: VRF_V2_WRAPPER.calculateRequestPrice(callbackGasLimit),
            randomWords: new uint256[](0),
            fulfilled: false
        });
        requestIds.push(requestId);
        lastRequestId = requestId;
        emit RequestSent(requestId, numWords);
        return requestId;
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256 _requestId,
        uint256[] memory _randomWords
    ) internal override {
        require(s_requests[_requestId].paid > 0, "request not found");
        s_requests[_requestId].fulfilled = true;
        s_requests[_requestId].randomWords = _randomWords;
        emit RequestFulfilled(
            _requestId,
            _randomWords,
            s_requests[_requestId].paid
        );
        payWinner();
    }

    function getRequestStatus(
        uint256 _requestId
    )
        external
        view
        returns (uint256 paid, bool fulfilled, uint256[] memory randomWords)
    {
        require(s_requests[_requestId].paid > 0, "request not found");
        RequestStatus memory request = s_requests[_requestId];
        return (request.paid, request.fulfilled, request.randomWords);
    }

    /**
     * Allow withdraw of Link tokens from the contract
     */
    function withdrawLink() public onlyOwner {
        LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(linkAddress);
        require(
            link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))),
            "Unable to transfer"
        );
    }


    function getWinnerByLottery(uint lottery) public view returns (address payable) {
        return lotteryHistory[lottery];
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function getPlayers() public view returns (address payable[] memory) {
        return players;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);

        // address of player entering lottery
        players.push(payable(msg.sender));
    }

    //function getRandomNumber() public view returns (uint) {
        //return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(owner, block.timestamp)));
    //}

    function pickWinner() public onlyowner {
        requestRandomWords;
    }

    function payWinner() public {
        uint index = lastRequestId % players.length;
        players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);

        lotteryHistory[lotteryId] = players[index];
        lotteryId++;
        

        // reset the state of the contract
        players = new address payable[](0);
    }

    modifier onlyowner() {
      require(msg.sender == owner);
      _;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0dYt.png)

Comment: Did you mean to do `requestRandomWords()` (note the parenthesis) instead?

Comment: yes, i tried to set 'requestRandomWords()' to the function pickWinner() as i think the  function 'requestRandomWords()' should be the function from the video - 'getRandomNumber()'

Comment: Also, in payWinner() i have set the value 'lastRequestId' instead of 'randomResult' from the video and have mentioned 'payWinner' in the function 'fulfillRandomWords()'